# How do I disable downgrading in WiX Bundle installer

Tags: wix

I have a WiX installer for my primary application, and I have created a bootstrapper project which holds two of the pre-requisites (ExePackages) for my primary application. Is there a way for me to prevent downgrading from my bundle installer to an older version of the primary application alone.
I thought of using MajorUpgrade but looks like it is not a feature for the bootstrapper project.

Answer (score 0):

*Update after clarification from the comments:*

Use `MajorUpgrade` in the MSI(s) and the `DowngradeErrorMessage` will be displayed if you try to install an older MSI after installing a newer MSI via a newer Bundle.

*Original answer:*

(almost) All UI in a bundle is defined by the BootstrapperApplication you use for your bundle. So displaying an error message to prevent downgrades is a BoostrapperApplication behavior.

For example, the `wixstdba` will display an error message when attempting to downgrade a bundle.

Comment: Currently I have been able to  show error messages when downgrading the application.msi but my issues is when I downgrade from bootstrapper.exe to application.msi, is there any way to approach this?

Comment: I don't really understand what you are asking. Is this the same question or a different question? If the former, I'd recommend improving your question above. If the latter, I'd recommend opening a new question.

Comment: It is the same question. I apologize for the confusion. Let me try framing this better.
I have a setup project to generate an msi file for my application, and the bootstrapper project holds all the pre-requisites for the same. If I download the bundle installer  (version 3.4) and then proceed to download just the application manually (version 3.2), the downgrading happens successfully. How do I prevent this?